# in node.js im unable to pass a variable to a member function of a class

Tags: node.js

I fixed this the right code is below

Im using mongodb and im trying to create a authentication function isAuthenticated that returns true or false if the user is in the database through a callback function. However I can't bring callback inside of client.connect . Im wondering why this is and what I could do to do this.

```
function isAuthenticated(username, password, callback1)
{

  //callback1(true); <<<<<<<<<THIS WORKS HERE

  client.connect(function(err, callback1) {      //client.connect is the mongodb client object

    //callback1(true); <<<<<<< THIS DOESNT WORK HERE SAYS callback is not a function

  });
}


////
////


//this is how im calling the isAthenticated function in my route
isAuthenticated("user1", "pass1", function(result)
{
    console.log("callback ran");
    console.log("result: " + result);
});
```

right code:

```
function isAuthenticated(username, password, callback1)
{

  return callback1(true); <<<<<<<<<THIS WORKS HERE

  client.connect(function(err) {      //client.connect is the mongodb client object

    return callback1(true); <<<<<<< WORKS NOW

  });
}


////
////


//this is how im calling the isAthenticated function in my route
isAuthenticated("user1", "pass1", function(result)
{
    console.log("callback ran");
    console.log("result: " + result);
});
```

Comment: please rename the two callbacks as `callback1` and `callback2` because even I am not sure which callback you're trying to call

Comment: I edited the names of callback

Comment: Looks like the first callback is finishing before client.connect gets called. I posted a suggestion to move promises, you can also use async/await to manage your flow.

Comment: https://youtu.be/DwQJ_NPQWWo watch this If you can. It's abasic intro to async/await.

Comment: are you saying that the second callback1(true) which is under client.connect is finishing before client.connect is called? So the things that are inside client.connect are run before client.connect itself?

Comment: if you are using ES5 notation you have to use `.bind(this)` in your `client.connect` function. If you use `ES6 arrow` notations it will be okay

Comment: Please rename the two callbacks `callback1` and `callback2`. Your problem is you have two different callbacks with the same name and I don't know which callback you want to call

Comment: OK. I took a look at mongoDB `connect()` method and it is supposed to be `client.connect(url, function (err, connection) {})`. The second argument of the callback function is not a callback but the database connection. Please rename your second `callback1` to `result` because it is not a function, it is the database connection. This will fix your issues

Answer (score 0):

Turn isAuthenticated into a promise and resolve instead of using a callback is quick and (in my limited experience) better for controlling the flow. That's if you can use promises of course.

```
function isAuthenticated(usename,pass){
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
... insert code here...
})});
    isAuthenticated("user1", "pass1")
.then((result)=>
{
    console.log("callback ran");
    console.log("result: " + result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a very big misunderstanding of how functions work in javascript. First, let's fix your bug. Simply remove the second `callback1` in your code:

```
function isAuthenticated(username, password, callback1)
{

  client.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    callback1(true); <<<<<<< THIS WORKS PERFECTLY FINE
  });

}
```

Explaining the basics of how all this works in javascript is beyond the scope of a single answer. It involves first-class functions, anonymous functions and closures - that's at least two question's worth of answers. I suggest you google "javascript first class functions" and watch/read through the articles and tutorials.